# Using AutoHotKey to choose a SysListView32 Item

Tags: autohotkey, syslistview32

I'm currently developing an automation script that gets information from an ERP software. I chose AutoHotkey because it's what the company uses for it's automation jobs.
However i got stuck trying to select an item from a SysListView32 control, which isn't the same as a ListView control apparently. Currently i'm able to send {Down} key strokes multiple times until i find the specific control, however i'd like to find a more elegant way like

```
Control, ChooseString, "String", WinName
```

Do you know if AHK is capable of such? Or do you know if there are other ways that are similar?

Comment: Try [ControlFocus](https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/ControlFocus.htm).

Comment: What results have you got using ControlGet? Specifically the List Sub-Command. The ControlGet command is very versatility but can be difficult to use. The help file contains a good explanation of the Command including an explanation for using a parsing loop to extract the individual rows and fields out of a ListView. Sometimes you have to trade off a bit of elegance for a bit of it isn't pretty but it works.

Comment: If you're not able to get the information you need from WindowSpy, I've found that ACC Viewer works really well. It can be downloaded from here: https://www.autohotkey.com/boards/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=26201